# how to change back button in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic3

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-navbar>
  <ion-buttons left>
   <button ion-button navPop icon-only>
    <ion-icon ios="ios-arrow-back" md="nbsons-arrow-back"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>distributor</ion-title>
   </ion-navbar>
 </ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
</ion-content>
```

I am completely new to Ionic 3, could some one please tell me how to change back button icon in ionic 3 for Android

Comment: what does your code show?

Answer (score 1):

What is this ? `md="nbsons-arrow-back"`

Try Like this

try to replace this one

```
 <ion-header>
     <ion-navbar>
      <ion-buttons left>
       <button ion-button navPop icon-only>
        <ion-icon ios="ios-arrow-back" md="md-arrow-back"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>distributor</ion-title>
       </ion-navbar>
     </ion-header>
    <ion-content padding>

</ion-content>
```

and learn more  about **ionicons**  [IonicIocns](https://ionicframework.com/docs/ionicons/)

Comment: basically i need to change this md="md-arrow-back into my custom icon